# Pymodbus : Wrong byte count in response

Tags: python, serial-port, modbus, pymodbus

We are requesting 14 responses from an RS485 device and sometimes the reply that we got doesn't have the 9 bytes that it is set-up. That is because it's replying sometimes in 3 arguments.

```
Normal: 
CALL->     01 04 00 00 00 02 71 CB 
RESPONSE-> 01 04 04 43 59 E6 66 F4 59


Error:
CALL->      01 04 00 00 00 02 71 CB 
RESPONSE -> 01 04 04 43
            59 CC CD AA 86
```

When the error happens i get this msg from pymodbus:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction: Incomplete message received, Expected 9 bytes Recieved 4 bytes !!!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x4 0x3e
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x4 0x4 0x3e
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
```

i've tried putting a sleep into the for so it dosn't colapse the device with calls but i get them either way. i've also read https://wingpath.co.uk/docs/modtest/troubleshoot.html
and they say this:

```
"Wrong byte count in response: XXX when expecting XXX"

The byte count in the response sent by the slave is not what was expected for the count that ModTest sent in the request.

Turn on tracing to get more information.

Check that your slave is functioning correctly.

If you want ModTest to accept the response even though it is incorrect, you could deselect Strict Checking.
```

But i don't know how to active tracing on PYMODBUS, the function is correct and the other one is for a lib that i am not using i think

THE CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
from __future__ import division
import pymodbus
import serial
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient #initialize a serial RTU client instance
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
from time import sleep
from pymodbus.constants import Endian              # Nodig voor 32-bit float getallen (2 registers / 4 bytes)
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder  # Nodig voor 32-bit float getallen (2 registers / 4 bytes)
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder  # Nodig om 32-bit floats te schrijven naar register

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

#

```
method = "rtu"
port = "COM1"
baudrate = 2400
stopbits = 1
bytesize = 8
parity = "N"
timeout = 10 # I SET THIS TO 10 MAYBE IT WOULD HELP BUT DIDN'T
retries = 5  # SAME THING WITH THIS ONE
```

#

```
try:
    client = ModbusClient(method = method, port = port, stopbits = stopbits, bytesize = bytesize, parity = parity, baudrate = baudrate, timeout = timeout, retries = retries)
    connection = client.connect()
    print (connection)
except:
    print ("Modbus connectie error")
```

#

```
def 420 (y):
    variables = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,70,72,74,76,78,342,344]
    labels = ["Voltage","Corriente","Potencia_Activa","Potencia_Aparente","Potencia_Reactiva","Factor_Potencia","Angulo_Fase","Frecuencia","Potencial_Activa_Consumida","Potencia_Activa_Inyectada","Potencia_Reactiva_Consumida","Potencia_Reactiva_Inyectada","Energia_Activa_Total","Energia_Reactiva_Total"]
    unidades = ["V","A","W","VA","VAr","%","Grados","HZ","kWh","kWh","kVArh","kVArh","kWh","kVArh"]
    LISTA = []
    h = 0
    hh = 0
    for xx in variables:
        try:
            data = client.read_input_registers(xx, 2, unit=1)
            decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(data.registers, Endian.Big)
            eastron = round(decoder.decode_32bit_float(), 3)
            weaito = str(labels[h]) + " = " + str(eastron) + " " + str(unidades[hh])
            LISTA.append(weaito)
            h = h + 1
            hh = hh + 1
            sleep(0.5)
        except:
            print ("PICO")
            sleep(1)
    print(LISTA)
```

I Would love a way around the problem, maybe just consulting again until i get the right answer. I am not good with the try and except ones maybe there is the answer.

Comment: You need to fill up a queue with the bytes received and only parse the response once you get enough bytes for a full message. You're dealing with two asynchronous devices communicating with eachother and sometimes you wont get the full message in a single read.. you need to give the device enough time to finish replying.

Comment: Yes that will do but the thing is how to code it, i don't really knnow if Pymodbus have that configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be experiencing a known [issue](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/353) with interchar spacing.

There is an easy workaround though. First, make sure you're on pymodbus version 2.2.0 (you can do that opening a command line terminal on Windows and typing `pip list` if you have the path setup correctly, otherwise you have to move to your scripts Python folder where `pip.exe` is stored).

Then change your code to add the `strict` argument declared to `False`:

```
....
client = ModbusClient(method = method, port = port, stopbits = stopbits, bytesize = bytesize, parity = parity, baudrate = baudrate, timeout = timeout, retries = retries)
client.strict = False    #Use Modbus interchar spacing as timeout to prevent missing data for low baudrates
connection = client.connect()
...
```

This will define the character spacing according to the Modbus spec, to 1.5 times the bit time at the selected baudrate, instead of using the default from `socket.interCharTimeout`:

```
self._t0 = float((1 + 8 + 2)) / self.baudrate
self.inter_char_timeout = 1.5 * self._t0
```

If you can fix your issue with this solution, you should be able to reduce the overhead on your device reading the 28 registers you want in one go.

If your issue is not solved, I think you might have a hardware issue. I would advise you to put your code aside for a while and try reading registers with [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/) or something similar to make sure your hardware is performing as intended. (you might be getting noise or grounding issues that cut your frames short, if you want some pointers on that front please edit your question to include more details on your hardware, i.e.: kind of devices and how you're connecting them).

Comment: These are the best fixes, just one line! I'm glad it worked.

Comment: I had lots of problems very similar to this, but this solution didn't help. Then I stumbled on a related solution that worked for me in a comment on the [PyModbus bugtracker](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/353#issuecomment-430531230) - I *only* had to use a different inter-char timeout: 
`client.inter_char_timeout = 0.05`