# multi-slave PYMODBUS Serial data loss

Tags: python, pymodbus

I have two computers running as slaves with pymodbus, when I do the individual reading they work very well, but when I try to read both at the same time I start to have data loss.

This is the master:

```
clienteRTU1 = ClientRTU(baudrate=9600, parity='N', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=0.3)
clienteRTU2 = ClientRTU(slave=2, baudrate=9600, parity='N', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=0.3)
vector = range(0, 10)
tx = [0, 0]
rx = [0, 0]
error = [0, 0]

t = time.time()
esclavo1 = [0,0]
esclavo2 = [0,0]

while True:

    print('transmision A: %d | recepcion A: %d | Error: %d' % (tx[0], rx[0], error[0]))
    print(esclavo1[0])
    print('transmision B: %d | recepcion B: %d | Error: %d' % (tx[1], rx[1], error[1]))
    print(esclavo2[0])
    print('Tiempo Comunicacion = ', time.time() - t)
    print('\n'*5)

    # ------------------------ Equipo 1 ----------------------------------- #
    esclavo1 = clienteRTU1.Read_ModRTU(vector, 3, slave=1)
    tx[0] += 1
    if esclavo1[2] == 0:
        rx[0] += 1
    else:
        error[0] += 1

    time.sleep(0.1)

    # ------------------------ Equipo 1 ----------------------------------- #
    esclavo2 = clienteRTU2.Read_ModRTU(vector, 3, slave=2)
    tx[1] += 1
    if esclavo2[2] == 0:
        rx[1] += 1
    else:
        error[1] += 1

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

And these are the slaves:

```
class ServidorSCADA:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.filas_hr = kwargs.get('filas_hr', 10)

        self.portRTU = kwargs.get("portRTU", "/dev/ttyUSB0")
        self.slave = kwargs.get("slave", 5)
        self.baudrate = kwargs.get("baudrate", 9600)
        self.parity = kwargs.get("parity", "N")
        self.timeout = kwargs.get("timeout", 0.1)
        self.bytesize = kwargs.get("bytesize", 8)
        self.stopbits = kwargs.get("stopbits", 1)

        self.TCPaddress = kwargs.get("address", "10.10.14.87")
        self.portTCP = kwargs.get("portTCP", 502)

        block_hr = CustomDataBlock([0]*self.filas_hr)
        block_ir = CustomDataBlock([0]*10)
        block_co = CustomDataBlock([0]*10)
        block_di = CustomDataBlock([0]*10)
        self.store = ModbusSlaveContext(
            di=block_di,
            co=block_co,
            hr=block_hr,
            ir=block_ir)
        self.contextRTU = ModbusServerContext(slaves={int(self.slave): self.store}, single=False)
        self.contextTCP = ModbusServerContext(slaves={1: self.store}, single=False)
        self.identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
        self.identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
        self.identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
        self.identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
        self.identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
        self.identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
        self.identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.5'

    def serverRTU(self):
        self.inicioRTU = StartSerialServer(context=self.contextRTU, identity=self.identity, port=self.portRTU,
                                     framer=ModbusRtuFramer, baudrate=self.baudrate,
                                     parity=self.parity, timeout=self.timeout, stopbits=self.stopbits,
                                     bytesize=self.bytesize, ignore_missing_slaves=True)

    def serverTCP(self):
        self.inicioTCP = StartTcpServer(context=self.contextTCP, identity=self.identity, address=(self.TCPaddress,
                                                                                                   self.portTCP))


def configuracionScada(self, direcciontcp):

    velocidadesPuerto = [9600, 19200, 38400, 57600]
    paridadPuerto = ['N', 'E', 'O']

    velocidadRTU = velocidadesPuerto[self.velocidadRTU]
    paridadRTU = paridadPuerto[self.paridadRTU]
    try:
        puertoRTU = self.puertostty[self.puertoRTU]
    except:
        puertoRTU = self.puertostty[0]

    self.filasWR = busquedaDB.numero_filasDb('Adicional/SCADA/Map_Server.db', 'HoldReg')
    filas = busquedaDB.numero_filasDb('Adicional/SCADA/variables_scada.db', 'variables')
    self.numeroFilasScada = self.filasWR.salida[0] + filas.salida[0] + 1
    self.servidorGeneral = ServidorSCADA(filas_hr=700, portRTU=puertoRTU, slave=self.direccionRTU,
                                         baudrate=velocidadRTU, parity=paridadRTU, address=direcciontcp,
                                         portTCP=self.puertoTCP)
    self.identidadScada = self.servidorGeneral.identity

    Thread(target=self.servidorGeneral.serverRTU).start()
    Thread(target=self.servidorGeneral.serverTCP).start()
```

These are the results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29YsL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPWnP.jpg)

this behavior happens if at least one of the slaves is pymodbus, if I add another slave for example a PLC, the problem persists

Comment: I have doubts about creating two (master) clients on the same port. Shouldn't it be a single one that consecutively reads from all slaves?

Comment: @Bosz yes, you are right, this code is the last attempt I made, but I used a PLC that uses a port and reads slaves sequentially, but the results were the same

Comment: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56659531/pymodbus-wrong-byte-count-in-response) with a solution that may be worth checking out.

Comment: @ Bosz Thanks, but I have the same problem with any master device, not just python, I think the problem is with the pymodbus serial server